# RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded caused by array.splice.apply?

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp, cheerio, gulp-cheerio

I'm running a cheerio task and it throws an exception that prints this (Note that I added the log statements that print the size of `spliceArgs` and `array`:

```
    [14:17:08] Starting 'test:css'...
    SPLICE ARGS LENGTH:  4
    ARRAY LENGTH:  5
    SPLICE ARGS LENGTH:  132519
    ARRAY LENGTH:  0
    /home/ole/@superflycss/utilities-fonts/node_modules/cheerio/lib/api/manipulation.js:109
      return array.splice.apply(array, spliceArgs);
                          ^

    RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
        at uniqueSplice (/home/ole/@superflycss/utilities-fonts/node_modules/cheerio/lib/api/manipulation.js:109:23)
        at /home/ole/Junk/@superflycss/utilities-fonts/node_modules/cheerio/lib/api/manipulation.js:133:3
        at initialize.<anonymous> (/home/ole/@superflycss/utilities-fonts/node_modules/cheerio/lib/api/manipulation.js
```

The line of code within `manipulation.js` triggering this exception is:

```
  return array.splice.apply(array, spliceArgs);
```

I also filed a [bug report that has a link](https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio/issues/1051) plus build and test instructions to the repository producing this exception.

Anyone know whether there is a NodeJS configuration setting that I can use to get around this?  The task is very sluggish in general and takes a long time to complete.

### Update

Just adding some additional info.  The `spliceArgs` array has a 132,519 items on it when the exception occurs.  I logged what the last items looks like and it's a fairly heavy object like this:

```
    { type: 'tag',
      name: 'div',
      attribs: { class: 'Test_render' },
      children: [],
      next: 
       { data: '\n      ',
         type: 'text',
         next: null,
         prev: [Circular],
         parent: 
          { type: 'tag',
            name: 'div',
            attribs: [Object],
            children: [Array],
            next: [Object],
            prev: [Object],
            parent: [Object] } },
      prev: 
       { data: '\n    ',
         type: 'text',
         next: [Circular],
         prev: 
          { type: 'tag',
            name: 'div',
            attribs: [Object],
            children: [Array],
            next: [Circular],
            prev: [Object],
            parent: [Object] },
         parent: 
          { type: 'tag',
            name: 'div',
            attribs: [Object],
            children: [Array],
            next: [Object],
            prev: [Object],
            parent: [Object] },
         root: null },
      parent: 
       { type: 'tag',
         name: 'div',
         attribs: { class: 'Test_output' },
         children: [ [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object] ],
         next: 
          { data: '\n    ',
            type: 'text',
            next: null,
            prev: [Circular],
            parent: [Object] },
         prev: 
          { data: '\n      ',
            type: 'text',
            next: [Circular],
            prev: [Object],
            parent: [Object] },
         parent: 
          { type: 'tag',
            name: 'div',
            attribs: [Object],
            children: [Array],
            next: [Object],
            prev: [Object],
            parent: [Object] } },
      root: null }
    SPLICE ARGS LENGTH:  4
    ARRAY LENGTH:  5
    SPLICE ARGS CONTENT: { data: '\n          ',
      type: 'text',
      next: null,
      prev: 
       { type: 'tag',
         name: 'div',
         attribs: { class: 'u-flex u-flex-column u-width-40rem' },
         children: [ [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object] ],
         next: [Circular],
         prev: 
          { data: '\n',
            type: 'text',
            next: [Circular],
            prev: [Object],
            parent: [Object],
            root: null },
         parent: 
          { type: 'tag',
            name: 'div',
            attribs: [Object],
            children: [],
            next: [Object],
            prev: [Object],
            parent: [Object],
            root: null },
         root: null },
      parent: 
       { type: 'tag',
         name: 'div',
         attribs: { class: 'Test_render' },
         children: [],
         next: 
          { data: '\n      ',
            type: 'text',
            next: null,
            prev: [Circular],
            parent: [Object] },
         prev: 
          { data: '\n    ',
            type: 'text',
            next: [Circular],
            prev: [Object],
            parent: [Object],
            root: null },
         parent: 
          { type: 'tag',
            name: 'div',
            attribs: [Object],
            children: [Array],
            next: [Object],
            prev: [Object],
            parent: [Object] },
         root: null },
      root: null }
```

So perhaps if we shoe horn in 132 thousand of these babies into an array that causes node to blow up?

### Second update

Since the `array` instances length is zero at the time exception occurs, I just returned `spliceArgs` instead of actually doing the splice like this:

```
  if (array.length == 0) {
     return spliceArgs;
  }
```

Now V8 runs out of memory:

```
      <--- Last few GCs --->

      [10392:0x247c600]    39418 ms: Mark-sweep 1404.6 (1451.9) -> 1404.4 (1428.9) MB, 2448.2 / 0.0 ms  (+ 0.0 ms in 0 steps since start of marking, biggest step 0.0 ms, walltime since start of marking 2448 ms) last resort 
      [10392:0x247c600]    41855 ms: Mark-sweep 1404.4 (1428.9) -> 1404.4 (1428.9) MB, 2436.3 / 0.0 ms  last resort 


      <--- JS stacktrace --->

      ==== JS stack trace =========================================

      Security context: 0x11ea432a9891 <JS Object>
          2: processKeywords [/home/ole/Junk/@superflycss/utilities-fonts/node_modules/highlight.js/lib/highlight.js:~366] [pc=0x39e06d9a7a8e](this=0x2b357c11c01 <JS Global Object>)
          3: processBuffer [/home/ole/Junk/@superflycss/utilities-fonts/node_modules/highlight.js/lib/highlight.js:~415] [pc=0x39e06d9a9cf9](this=0x2b357c11c01 <JS Global Object>)
          4: processLexeme [/home/ole/Junk/@superflyc...

      FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
       1: node::Abort() [gulp]
       2: 0x13647ec [gulp]
       3: v8::Utils::ReportOOMFailure(char const*, bool) [gulp]
       4: v8::internal::V8::FatalProcessOutOfMemory(char const*, bool) [gulp]
       5: v8::internal::Factory::NewFillerObject(int, bool, v8::internal::AllocationSpace) [gulp]
       6: v8::internal::Runtime_AllocateInTargetSpace(int, v8::internal::Object**, v8::internal::Isolate*) [gulp]
       7: 0x39e06ce8437d
      Aborted (core dumped)
```

### Another update

This is not a cheerio issue.  I tried implementing the same thing in JSDOM and node still can't handle it even with 6GB of ram allocated:

```
 node --max-old-space-size=6000 ./node_modules/.bin/gulp test:css
```

I'm surprised by this because the html file, once the nunjucks loops have run, is 9X9X816 template blocks in size.  These are the loops:

```
      {% for font in ['abeezee', 'abel', 'abhaya-libre', 'abril-fatface', 'aclonica', 'acme', 'actor', 'adamina', 'advent-pro', 'aguafina-script', 'akronim', 'aladin', 'aldrich', 'alef', 'alegreya', 'alegreya-sc', 'alegreya-sans', 'alegreya-sans-sc', 'alex-brush', 'alfa-slab-one', 'alice', 'alike', 'alike-angular', 'allan', 'allerta', 'allerta-stencil', 'allura', 'almendra', 'almendra-display', 'almendra-sc', 'amarante', 'amaranth', 'amatic-sc', 'amatica-sc', 'amethysta', 'amiko', 'amiri', 'amita', 'anaheim', 'andada', 'andika', 'angkor', 'annie-use-your-telescope', 'anonymous-pro', 'antic', 'antic-didone', 'antic-slab', 'anton', 'arapey', 'arbutus', 'arbutus-slab', 'architects-daughter', 'archivo-black', 'archivo-narrow', 'aref-ruqaa', 'arima-madurai', 'arimo', 'arizonia', 'armata', 'arsenal', 'artifika', 'arvo', 'arya', 'asap', 'asar', 'asset', 'assistant', 'astloch', 'asul', 'athiti', 'atma', 'atomic-age', 'aubrey', 'audiowide', 'autour-one', 'average', 'average-sans', 'averia-gruesa-libre', 'averia-libre', 'averia-sans-libre', 'averia-serif-libre', 'bad-script', 'bahiana', 'baloo', 'baloo-bhai', 'baloo-bhaina', 'baloo-chettan', 'baloo-da', 'baloo-paaji', 'baloo-tamma', 'baloo-thambi', 'balthazar', 'bangers', 'barrio', 'basic', 'battambang', 'baumans', 'bayon', 'belgrano', 'belleza', 'benchnine', 'bentham', 'berkshire-swash', 'bevan', 'bigelow-rules', 'bigshot-one', 'bilbo', 'bilbo-swash-caps', 'biorhyme', 'biorhyme-expanded', 'biryani', 'bitter', 'black-ops-one', 'bokor', 'bonbon', 'boogaloo', 'bowlby-one', 'bowlby-one-sc', 'brawler', 'bree-serif', 'bubblegum-sans', 'bubbler-one', 'buda', 'buenard', 'bungee', 'bungee-hairline', 'bungee-inline', 'bungee-outline', 'bungee-shade', 'butcherman', 'butterfly-kids', 'cabin', 'cabin-condensed', 'cabin-sketch', 'caesar-dressing', 'cagliostro', 'cairo', 'calligraffitti', 'cambay', 'cambo', 'candal', 'cantarell', 'cantata-one', 'cantora-one', 'capriola', 'cardo', 'carme', 'carrois-gothic', 'carrois-gothic-sc', 'carter-one', 'catamaran', 'caudex', 'caveat', 'caveat-brush', 'cedarville-cursive', 'ceviche-one', 'changa', 'changa-one', 'chango', 'chathura', 'chau-philomene-one', 'chela-one', 'chelsea-market', 'chenla', 'cherry-cream-soda', 'cherry-swash', 'chewy', 'chicle', 'chivo', 'chonburi', 'cinzel', 'cinzel-decorative', 'clicker-script', 'coda', 'coda-caption', 'codystar', 'coiny', 'combo', 'comfortaa', 'coming-soon', 'concert-one', 'condiment', 'content', 'contrail-one', 'convergence', 'cookie', 'copse', 'corben', 'cormorant', 'cormorant-garamond', 'cormorant-infant', 'cormorant-sc', 'cormorant-unicase', 'cormorant-upright', 'courgette', 'cousine', 'coustard', 'covered-by-your-grace', 'crafty-girls', 'creepster', 'crete-round', 'crimson-text', 'croissant-one', 'crushed', 'cuprum', 'cutive', 'cutive-mono', 'damion', 'dancing-script', 'dangrek', 'david-libre', 'dawning-of-a-new-day', 'days-one', 'dekko', 'delius', 'delius-swash-caps', 'delius-unicase', 'della-respira', 'denk-one', 'devonshire', 'dhurjati', 'didact-gothic', 'diplomata', 'diplomata-sc', 'domine', 'donegal-one', 'doppio-one', 'dorsa', 'dosis', 'dr-sugiyama', 'droid-sans', 'droid-sans-mono', 'droid-serif', 'duru-sans', 'dynalight', 'eb-garamond', 'eagle-lake', 'eater', 'economica', 'eczar', 'ek-mukta', 'el-messiri', 'electrolize', 'elsie', 'elsie-swash-caps', 'emblema-one', 'emilys-candy', 'engagement', 'englebert', 'enriqueta', 'erica-one', 'esteban', 'euphoria-script', 'ewert', 'exo', 'exo-2', 'expletus-sans', 'fanwood-text', 'farsan', 'fascinate', 'fascinate-inline', 'faster-one', 'fasthand', 'fauna-one', 'federant', 'federo', 'felipa', 'fenix', 'finger-paint', 'fira-mono', 'fira-sans', 'fira-sans-condensed', 'fira-sans-extra-condensed', 'fjalla-one', 'fjord-one', 'flamenco', 'flavors', 'fondamento', 'fontdiner-swanky', 'forum', 'francois-one', 'frank-ruhl-libre', 'freckle-face', 'fredericka-the-great', 'fredoka-one', 'freehand', 'fresca', 'frijole', 'fruktur', 'fugaz-one', 'gfs-didot', 'gfs-neohellenic', 'gabriela', 'gafata', 'galada', 'galdeano', 'galindo', 'gentium-basic', 'gentium-book-basic', 'geo', 'geostar', 'geostar-fill', 'germania-one', 'gidugu', 'gilda-display', 'give-you-glory', 'glass-antiqua', 'glegoo', 'gloria-hallelujah', 'goblin-one', 'gochi-hand', 'gorditas', 'goudy-bookletter-1911', 'graduate', 'grand-hotel', 'gravitas-one', 'great-vibes', 'griffy', 'gruppo', 'gudea', 'gurajada', 'habibi', 'halant', 'hammersmith-one', 'hanalei', 'hanalei-fill', 'handlee', 'hanuman', 'happy-monkey', 'harmattan', 'headland-one', 'heebo', 'henny-penny', 'herr-von-muellerhoff', 'hind', 'hind-guntur', 'hind-madurai', 'hind-siliguri', 'hind-vadodara', 'holtwood-one-sc', 'homemade-apple', 'homenaje', 'im-fell-dw-pica', 'im-fell-dw-pica-sc', 'im-fell-double-pica', 'im-fell-double-pica-sc', 'im-fell-english', 'im-fell-english-sc', 'im-fell-french-canon', 'im-fell-french-canon-sc', 'im-fell-great-primer', 'im-fell-great-primer-sc', 'iceberg', 'iceland', 'imprima', 'inconsolata', 'inder', 'indie-flower', 'inika', 'inknut-antiqua', 'irish-grover', 'istok-web', 'italiana', 'italianno', 'itim', 'jacques-francois', 'jacques-francois-shadow', 'jaldi', 'jim-nightshade', 'jockey-one', 'jolly-lodger', 'jomhuria', 'josefin-sans', 'josefin-slab', 'joti-one', 'judson', 'julee', 'julius-sans-one', 'junge', 'jura', 'just-another-hand', 'just-me-again-down-here', 'kadwa', 'kalam', 'kameron', 'kanit', 'kantumruy', 'karla', 'karma', 'katibeh', 'kaushan-script', 'kavivanar', 'kavoon', 'kdam-thmor', 'keania-one', 'kelly-slab', 'kenia', 'khand', 'khmer', 'khula', 'kite-one', 'knewave', 'kotta-one', 'koulen', 'kranky', 'kreon', 'kristi', 'krona-one', 'kumar-one', 'kumar-one-outline', 'kurale', 'la-belle-aurore', 'laila', 'lakki-reddy', 'lalezar', 'lancelot', 'lateef', 'lato', 'league-script', 'leckerli-one', 'ledger', 'lekton', 'lemon', 'lemonada', 'libre-baskerville', 'libre-franklin', 'life-savers', 'lilita-one', 'lily-script-one', 'limelight', 'linden-hill', 'lobster', 'lobster-two', 'londrina-outline', 'londrina-shadow', 'londrina-sketch', 'londrina-solid', 'lora', 'love-ya-like-a-sister', 'loved-by-the-king', 'lovers-quarrel', 'luckiest-guy', 'lusitana', 'lustria', 'macondo', 'macondo-swash-caps', 'mada', 'magra', 'maiden-orange', 'maitree', 'mako', 'mallanna', 'mandali', 'marcellus', 'marcellus-sc', 'marck-script', 'margarine', 'marko-one', 'marmelad', 'martel', 'martel-sans', 'marvel', 'mate', 'mate-sc', 'maven-pro', 'mclaren', 'meddon', 'medievalsharp', 'medula-one', 'meera-inimai', 'megrim', 'meie-script', 'merienda', 'merienda-one', 'merriweather', 'merriweather-sans', 'metal', 'metal-mania', 'metamorphous', 'metrophobic', 'michroma', 'milonga', 'miltonian', 'miltonian-tattoo', 'miniver', 'miriam-libre', 'mirza', 'miss-fajardose', 'mitr', 'modak', 'modern-antiqua', 'mogra', 'molengo', 'molle', 'monda', 'monofett', 'monoton', 'monsieur-la-doulaise', 'montaga', 'montez', 'montserrat', 'montserrat-alternates', 'montserrat-subrayada', 'moul', 'moulpali', 'mountains-of-christmas', 'mouse-memoirs', 'mr-bedfort', 'mr-dafoe', 'mr-de-haviland', 'mrs-saint-delafield', 'mrs-sheppards', 'mukta-vaani', 'muli', 'mystery-quest', 'ntr', 'neucha', 'neuton', 'new-rocker', 'news-cycle', 'niconne', 'nixie-one', 'nobile', 'nokora', 'norican', 'nosifer', 'nothing-you-could-do', 'noticia-text', 'noto-sans', 'noto-serif', 'nova-cut', 'nova-flat', 'nova-mono', 'nova-oval', 'nova-round', 'nova-script', 'nova-slim', 'nova-square', 'numans', 'nunito', 'nunito-sans', 'odor-mean-chey', 'offside', 'old-standard-tt', 'oldenburg', 'oleo-script', 'oleo-script-swash-caps', 'open-sans', 'open-sans-condensed', 'oranienbaum', 'orbitron', 'oregano', 'orienta', 'original-surfer', 'oswald', 'over-the-rainbow', 'overlock', 'overlock-sc', 'overpass', 'overpass-mono', 'ovo', 'oxygen', 'oxygen-mono', 'pt-mono', 'pt-sans', 'pt-sans-caption', 'pt-sans-narrow', 'pt-serif', 'pt-serif-caption', 'pacifico', 'padauk', 'palanquin', 'palanquin-dark', 'pangolin', 'paprika', 'parisienne', 'passero-one', 'passion-one', 'pathway-gothic-one', 'patrick-hand', 'patrick-hand-sc', 'pattaya', 'patua-one', 'pavanam', 'paytone-one', 'peddana', 'peralta', 'permanent-marker', 'petit-formal-script', 'petrona', 'philosopher', 'piedra', 'pinyon-script', 'pirata-one', 'plaster', 'play', 'playball', 'playfair-display', 'playfair-display-sc', 'podkova', 'poiret-one', 'poller-one', 'poly', 'pompiere', 'pontano-sans', 'poppins', 'port-lligat-sans', 'port-lligat-slab', 'pragati-narrow', 'prata', 'preahvihear', 'press-start-2p', 'pridi', 'princess-sofia', 'prociono', 'prompt', 'prosto-one', 'proza-libre', 'puritan', 'purple-purse', 'quando', 'quantico', 'quattrocento', 'quattrocento-sans', 'questrial', 'quicksand', 'quintessential', 'qwigley', 'racing-sans-one', 'radley', 'rajdhani', 'rakkas', 'raleway', 'raleway-dots', 'ramabhadra', 'ramaraja', 'rambla', 'rammetto-one', 'ranchers', 'rancho', 'ranga', 'rasa', 'rationale', 'ravi-prakash', 'redressed', 'reem-kufi', 'reenie-beanie', 'revalia', 'rhodium-libre', 'ribeye', 'ribeye-marrow', 'righteous', 'risque', 'roboto', 'roboto-condensed', 'roboto-mono', 'roboto-slab', 'rochester', 'rock-salt', 'rokkitt', 'romanesco', 'ropa-sans', 'rosario', 'rosarivo', 'rouge-script', 'rozha-one', 'rubik', 'rubik-mono-one', 'ruda', 'rufina', 'ruge-boogie', 'ruluko', 'rum-raisin', 'ruslan-display', 'russo-one', 'ruthie', 'rye', 'sacramento', 'sahitya', 'sail', 'salsa', 'sanchez', 'sancreek', 'sansita', 'sarala', 'sarina', 'sarpanch', 'satisfy', 'scada', 'scheherazade', 'schoolbell', 'scope-one', 'seaweed-script', 'secular-one', 'sevillana', 'seymour-one', 'shadows-into-light', 'shadows-into-light-two', 'shanti', 'share', 'share-tech', 'share-tech-mono', 'shojumaru', 'short-stack', 'shrikhand', 'siemreap', 'sigmar-one', 'signika', 'signika-negative', 'simonetta', 'sintony', 'sirin-stencil', 'six-caps', 'skranji', 'slabo-13px', 'slabo-27px', 'slackey', 'smokum', 'smythe', 'sniglet', 'snippet', 'snowburst-one', 'sofadi-one', 'sofia', 'sonsie-one', 'sorts-mill-goudy', 'source-code-pro', 'source-sans-pro', 'source-serif-pro', 'space-mono', 'special-elite', 'spicy-rice', 'spinnaker', 'spirax', 'squada-one', 'sree-krushnadevaraya', 'sriracha', 'stalemate', 'stalinist-one', 'stardos-stencil', 'stint-ultra-condensed', 'stint-ultra-expanded', 'stoke', 'strait', 'sue-ellen-francisco', 'suez-one', 'sumana', 'sunshiney', 'supermercado-one', 'sura', 'suranna', 'suravaram', 'suwannaphum', 'swanky-and-moo-moo', 'syncopate', 'tangerine', 'taprom', 'tauri', 'taviraj', 'teko', 'telex', 'tenali-ramakrishna', 'tenor-sans', 'text-me-one', 'the-girl-next-door', 'tienne', 'tillana', 'timmana', 'tinos', 'titan-one', 'titillium-web', 'trade-winds', 'trirong', 'trocchi', 'trochut', 'trykker', 'tulpen-one', 'ubuntu', 'ubuntu-condensed', 'ubuntu-mono', 'ultra', 'uncial-antiqua', 'underdog', 'unica-one', 'unifrakturcook', 'unifrakturmaguntia', 'unkempt', 'unlock', 'unna', 'vt323', 'vampiro-one', 'varela', 'varela-round', 'vast-shadow', 'vesper-libre', 'vibur', 'vidaloka', 'viga', 'voces', 'volkhov', 'vollkorn', 'voltaire', 'waiting-for-the-sunrise', 'wallpoet', 'walter-turncoat', 'warnes', 'wellfleet', 'wendy-one', 'wire-one', 'work-sans', 'yanone-kaffeesatz', 'yantramanav', 'yatra-one', 'yellowtail', 'yeseva-one', 'yesteryear', 'yrsa', 'zeyada'] %}
      {% for weight in ['100','200','300','400','500','600','700','800','900']%}
      {% for size in ['100','200','300','400','500','600','700','800','900']%}
      <div class="u-flex u-flex-column u-width-40rem">
        <div class="u-flex u-width-40rem">
          <div class="u-flex-auto
                      u-padding-1rem
                      u-font-inconsolata
                      u-font-weight-400
                      u-font-size-300
                      u-border-style-solid
                      u-border-width-1px
                      u-border-color-gray">
                      u-font-weight-{{weight}}
          </div>
          <div class="u-flex-auto
                      u-padding-1rem
                      u-font-inconsolata
                      u-font-weight-400
                      u-font-size-300
                      u-border-style-solid
                      u-border-style-top-none
                      u-border-width-1px
                      u-border-color-gray">
                      u-font-size-{{size}}
          </div>
          <div class="u-flex-auto
                      u-padding-1rem
                      u-font-inconsolata
                      u-font-weight-400
                      u-font-size-300
                      u-border-style-solid
                      u-border-style-top-none
                      u-border-width-1px
                      u-border-color-gray">
                      u-font-{{font}}
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="u-font-{{font}}
                    u-font-weight-{{weight}}
                    u-font-size-{{size}}
                    u-flex
                    u-flex-justify-center
                    u-width-100
                    u-padding-1rem
                    u-border-style-solid
                    u-border-top-style-none
                    u-border-width-1px
                    u-border-color-gray
                    margin-bottom-1rem
                    u-background-color-white
                    u-text-color-md-grey-900">
          Word to the Dalai Lama!
        </div>
      </div>
      {%- endfor %}
      {%- endfor %}
      {%- endfor %}
```

So these render out and then the gulp task attempts to copy that block to another place in the document, before syntax highlighting is run on all of it.  Node runs into memory issues on the copy and append.

Comment: I have seen this happen in the past when code executes callbacks synchronously.  The synchronous execution of the callbacks never allowed the stack to roll back and resulted in this error.

Comment: Yeah I'm really scratching my head over this one.  All cheerio is doing is finding a section tagged Test_markup and transferring it to another section within the document.  In this case there is only one section.  The section contains three nested loops (All google fonts X font weights X font sizes - Or 816 X 9 X 9) iterations ... which generates a lot of markup ... so I'm thinking it is overflowing some buffer ... If I for example remove the font size loop, then it works fine, but I do need to take a small vacation while waiting for it to complete.

Comment: Here's an example of what it's doing:  https://superflycss.github.io/utilities-layout/target/test/html/

Comment: Notice that the markup is displayed on the left and the corresponding rendering on the right.  The same task is run against this layout module, and it runs fine.  The difference between the layout module and the font module is that the layout module has lots of small Test markup sections, and the font module has one massive one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are hitting the maximum argument size allowed by apply. If you reference https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply

> The consequences of applying a function with too many arguments (think more than tens of thousands of arguments) vary across engines (JavaScriptCore has hard-coded argument limit of 65536), because the limit (indeed even the nature of any excessively-large-stack behavior) is unspecified.

Comment: I have not verified it - but I think you are right.  There's some related info here: https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/1719

Comment: I noticed that at the time the exception occurs the first argument to the splice function has length zero.  So instead of splicing, I just returned the second argument.  Now V8 runs out of memory.  Posted the details in the cheerio bug report: https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio/issues/1051#issuecomment-313824058