# Is there a function to copy set of elements within a range in an array into a range in another array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a place in my javascript code where I need to do an operation like

**copying a specified range from one array into specified range in another array.**

The operation is similar to

1) [System.arraycopy](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy(java.lang.Object,%20int,%20java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int)) in java ->

```
System.arraycopy(array1, index1, array2, index3, index4 - index4 + 1);
```

2) [copy](https://golang.org/pkg/builtin/#copy) in go ->

`copy(array2[index3:index4 + 1], array1[index1:index2+1])`

3) slice in python ->

```
array2[index3: index4 + 1] = arr[index1: index2+1]
```

For now I am iterating it by hand and doing it.
But I did not any util function in js to do that. Is there really one ?

**Update 1**: It should exactly only copy and not add or remove elements from any of the two given arrays.

It should behave like this implementation:

```
function arraycopy(src, srcPos, dst, dstPos, length) {
    let j = dstPos;
    let tempArr = src.slice(srcPos, srcPos + length);
    for (let e in tempArr) {
        dst[j] =  tempArr[e];
        j++;
    }
};
```

**Update 2**: (See some answers below with caution and see if it will fit your use case(like in huge dataset case)) Many answers below used splice in such a way it will break, if the range start to end in source array is huge. It will throw "RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded"... as it will exceed the maximum allowed number of arguments in a function. (try demo script [here](https://gist.github.com/HarishAtGitHub/e61fb5134fc6855ac6774000e9b785f3)) "

Comment: You can splice a slice with `.splice` and `.slice`

Comment: you can see my answer if that help, basically mimicking the python function using slice and concat functions

Comment: I added a helper function to my answer that uses `concat()` to solve the `RangeError` problem, and also returns a new array, with the input arrays being unaltered.

Answer (score 3):

A combination of `slice` and `splice` is probably the way to go here. You can write a helper function that mimics the same behavior in other languages. Here's one that mirrors Java's `arraycopy` method:

```js
const arr1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
const arr2 = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"];

function arrayCopy(src, srcIndex, dest, destIndex, length) {
  dest.splice(destIndex, length, ...src.slice(srcIndex, srcIndex + length));
}

// copy from arr1, at position 0, into arr2, at position 2, 3 elements.
arrayCopy(arr1, 0, arr2, 2, 3);
console.log(arr2)
```

Comment: Warning: think we should not use this method, as it will break, if the range start to end in source array is huge. It will throw "RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded"... as it will exceed the maximum allowed arguments in a function. (stackoverflow.com/a/44978433/1597944)

Comment: This does not work for typed arrays like the Int8Array

Answer (score 2):

Nothing similar in JavaScript. There might be JavaScript libraries with similar functionality, but I am not aware of any. Simple loop and assignment will be much more efficient, as it avoids the overhead from function calls and making new arrays :

```js
function arraycopy(src, srcPos, dst, dstPos, length) {
    while (length--) dst[dstPos++] = src[srcPos++]; return dst;
}

console.log( arraycopy([2,3,4,5,6], 1, [1,1,1,1,1,1], 2, 3) )
```

---

Another inefficient alternative for completeness, is copying the values with `Object.assign` :

```js
function arraycopy(src, srcPos, dst, dstPos, length) {
    return Object.assign(dst, Array(dstPos).concat(src.slice(srcPos, srcPos + length)))
}

console.log( arraycopy([2,3,4,5,6], 1, [1,1,1,1,1,1], 2, 3) )
```

Answer (score 1):

Not a single function that I know of, but I think this functionality can be achieved using `slice()` and `splice()`.

> The slice() method slices out a piece of an array into a new array.
>
> The splice() method can be used to add new items to an array.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Array.prototype.splice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) (along with the method [Array.prototype.slice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)) method to do exactly what you are describing.

Say you want to copy from index 3 to 5 (inclusive) out of array `A` into index 3 of array `B` (replacing anything in `B` from index 3 to 5):

```js
const A = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
const B = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];

const start = 3;
const end = 6;

// Splice (end - start) elements starting at 3
// with elements from start to end in A
B.splice(3, end - start, ...A.slice(start, end));

console.log(B);
```

*Note: this also takes advantage of JavaScript's [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) which emits all individual values from the array returned by `A.slice()`.*

## Edit

Taking the following into consideration:

> **Update 1**: It should exactly only copy and not add or remove elements from any of the two given arrays.

and

> ...it will break, if the range start to end in source array is huge.

Consider the following function:

```js
function arrayCopy(arr1, index1, arr2, index2, length) {
    return []
        .concat(arr2.slice(0, index2))                  // Array 2 from beginning until the index to replace
        .concat(arr1.slice(index1, index1 + length))    // Array 1 from the index to copy for 'length' elements
        .concat(arr2.slice(index2 + length));           // Rest of Array 2, 'length' elements past the index to replace
}

const A = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
const B = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];

// Copy B into Z and replace Z[3] to Z[5] with A[3] to A[5]
const Z = arrayCopy(A, 3, B, 3, 3);

console.log('\'A\' after copy:');
console.log(A);
console.log('\'B\' after copy:');
console.log(B);
console.log('\'Z\' after copy:');
console.log(Z);

// Testing the method with arrays of length 2,000,000

const longArray = [];
const otherLongArray = [];

for (let i = 0; i < 2000000; i++) {
    longArray.push(i);
    otherLongArray.push(-i);
}

const newLongArray = arrayCopy(longArray, 0, otherLongArray, 1500000, 1000000);

console.log(newLongArray.length);
```

This will create a *new array* that is a copy of the second input array, but replaces `length` number of elements in that array (starting at `index2`) with `length` number of elements from the first input array (starting at `index1`). The function utilizes [Array.prototype.concat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) which takes a full array as an argument. This should alleviate the "callstack" error problem when the array is really large.

Comment: Your code inserts elements at an index. it should replace elements within that index. Just like how arraycopy in java works.

Comment: See my edited snippet for replacement, not simply injection.

Comment: Warning: think we should not use this method, as it will break, if the range start to end in source array is huge. It will throw "RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded"... as it will exceed the maximum allowed arguments in a function. (https://stackoverflow.com/a/44978433/1597944)

Comment: See my #Edit for a solution to the `RangeError` problem

Answer (score 1):

Another approach would be to use `slice` to cut out the elements you need from the source array (without altering it), then `forEach` to replace elements from the distination array with the cut out elements:

```
function arraycopy(src, srcPos, dst, dstPos, length) {
    src.slice(srcPos, srPos + length)
       .forEach((e, i) => dst[dstPos + i] = e);
}
```

**Example:**

```js
function arraycopy(src, srcPos, dst, dstPos, length) {
    src.slice(srcPos, srcPos + length)
       .forEach((e, i) => dst[dstPos + i] = e);
}

let arr1 = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
let arr2 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g'];

arraycopy(arr1, 2, arr2, 3, 3);

console.log("arr1: " + arr1);
console.log("arr2: " + arr2);
```

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript Array slice() and concat() Method fits your requirement.

```
var arr= ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"];
var arr2 = ["x","y","z"];
arr= arr.slice(0, index3).concat(arr2.slice(index1: index2+1)).concat(arr.slice(index4+1, arr.length));
```

[HTML file for trial](https://gist.github.com/jaskirat8/c03da832a4dbd71927a6430f26669325)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `slice` method to copy a range of elements from one array to another, and keeps to original array untouched.

The `slice` method accepts two arguments, the first one is the `start index` of the copy operation, the second argument is the `end index` of the copy operation, the `end index` **is not** included in the result array.

Here's an illustration of what being said:

```js
var arr1 = ['Hi ', 'there! ', 'How ', 'are ', 'you ?'];
var arr2 = arr1.slice(2, arr1.length);
console.log(arr2.toString());
// output: How ,are ,you ?
```

Learn more about [slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) method.